# Powershell shuffling output messages when issuing meteor update command

Tags: powershell, meteor, windows-10, posh-git

I have installed in windows 10 posh-git v0.7.0 environment to powershell to augment its functionality.

Unfortunately when issuing the meteor update inside powershell the output in the terminal is terribly shuffled making it very hard to understand the program flow.

meteor update before initializing git repository works fine as can ben seen in the following image.

[image]

meteor update after initializing git repository shuffles the terminal output as can be seen in the following image.

[image]

After updating poshgit to version v0.7.1 the error changed a bit to [Failed to import posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/381)

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: @jordanwillis, I updated the post with images to better represent the issue.

Comment: Hi Daniel I have the same exact error on my windows 10 powershell. Did you find any solution for this problem?